# Python return only the largest substrings string from a list of substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list sorted by element length generated from a input string
example :

```
tst_str =  "crystalapplehatcat"
```

I have subordinate functions that gets all continuous substrings from the list & removes any strings less than 2 chars in length.

```
#   return list : all continuous substrings
def get_all_substrings(input_string):
    length = len(input_string)
    return [input_string[i:j + 1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i, length)]


#   return list : pruned continuous substrings
def get_pruned_list(input_list, size_floor=2):
    pruned_list = []
    for element in input_list:
        if len(element) > size_floor:
            pruned_list.append(element)
    return pruned_list
```

The resultant list  that is to be process has the following form.

```
tst_list = ['crystal', 'cryst', 'apple', 'tala', 'alap', 'lapp', 'appl', 'cry', 'sta', 'tal', 'ala', 'lap', 'app', 'ppl', 'hat', 'cat']
```

I need to only return the largest unique string from the list :

```
result_list = ['crystal','apple','hat', 'cat']
```

I have been trying to use
`any()` to process the current element against the rest of the list but the returned values have been incorrect

Additional :
The input string can be as large as 128 characters.
Some input lists can have overlap strings = 'generalisedeep' from roots -> generalise deep ,
so only one string would be returned: ['generalised'] where it should be ['generalise', 'deep'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive approach would work, by tracking the longest coverage of word combinations (removing found words before recursing with the rest of the string):

```
def findWords(S,words):
    result = []
    for i,word in enumerate(words):
        if word not in S: continue
        match = [word]+findWords(S.replace(word," "),words[i+1:])
        if sum(map(len,match)) > sum(map(len,result)):
            result = match
    return result
```

output:

```
tst_str =  "crystalapplehatcat"
tst_list = ['crystal', 'cryst', 'apple', 'tala', 'alap', 'lapp', 'appl', 'cry', 'sta', 'tal', 'ala', 'lap', 'app', 'ppl', 'hat', 'cat']
print(findWords(tst_str,tst_list))
['crystal', 'apple', 'hat', 'cat']

tst_str  = "generalisedeep"
tst_list = ["generalised","generalise","deep"]
print(findWords(tst_str,tst_list))
['generalise', 'deep']
```